# Django queries with cursor slow

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with some queries that are taking 15 seconds onwards (it is a lot) with cursor in Djando (without using orm because it takes even more) and directly in mysql it takes 4 or 5 seconds, which I think I can be affecting

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select m.ub ,m.eq , MONTH(m.fecha) as fecha,
AVG(m.cantidad) as cantidad , e.contt from mytable as m 
left join table2 as e on e.id = m.equipo_id where m.equipo_id = %s and m.udm = 8 and 
YEAR(m.fecha) = %s  GROUP BY MONTH(m.fecha)",[eq,anio])
```

Comment: I recall having slow results using YEAR or MONTH, especially in WHERE conditions, depending on how consistent the data is in the column maybe you can avoid it or use regex?

Comment: I do not know if it is a problem of django cursor towards mysql because in mysql 4 queries it is done very fast and if the 4 questions with processes I try to make them with a cursor and the time too high to mysql configure it to allow more than 1 connection @EdoardoFacchinelli